# Why was the minimum comment length of 15 chosen?

Tags: discussion, comments, character-limit

Note: I am **not** asking why is there a minimum limit.

#### Previously closed as dup, but neither of the "duplicates" answer this question!!!

The suggested dups were:

- [*Can we get rid of the threshold of 15 chars for comments?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments)
- [*Why the 15 character minimum on comments?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68638/why-the-15-character-minimum-on-comments)

Both of which ask why the limit is there. I know why it's there.  I'm happy it's there.

This question is asking **why it is 15 (and not 14, or 16, etc)?**

Was *any* thought or research put into the choice, or was it just based on feel?

Some examples of reasons for choosing 15:

- Was some statistical analysis done on comment sizes?
- Was the limit borrowed from an external academic or commercial source?
- Was it decided on by committee?
- Is it because it's the largest length that can be represented by a single hex digit?

Also note: I don't think it's a bad limit or needs changing. I am just curious to know why 15 specifically was chosen.

The reason I'm asking is if the reason has firm basis it, that basis could be valuable info for someone researching lower thresholds of meaningful communication.

Comment: Unicorns fly in groups of 15. Thought it was obvious :)

Comment: `"spolsky atwood"` is 15 bytes long (including the `NUL` character).

Comment: @Łukasz, *[questioner is] not asking why is there a minimum limit*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but the answer to that questions gives an explanation: because 15 is mentioned in some holy quote from Jeff. Quotes from Jeff are considered holy because unicorns talk to him when he sleeps or something that way...

Comment: why is the max comment length 600

Comment: Guys, I'm asking why was 15 chosen. Those dups do not ask or answer that

Comment: It's the median age of emotional maturity of users on the site. Not sure if that's why it was picked, but just sayin'

Comment: @TimPost Maybe it's the median IQ of users on the site.

Comment: @TimPost ...Is not!

Comment: I have a feeling the only serious answer here is "no special reason". Just a moment decision by Jeff when he wrote the code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard et al., the answer to "Why this particular number?" is almost always "Because we had to pick one and this one felt about right." The answer to "Why a minimum at all?" is more interesting and addressed in other places.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Sure, but I am curious if *any* thought or research went into it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you seem to doubt that Jeff really spoke with unicorns in his dreams ;)

Comment: Actually, "How to run it?" and "givemethekodez" happen to have 14 characters, but on the other side, "how to run it?" and "me run not too" are exactly 15, which would make them "allowed". Maybe it's so low to allow "Show your code" comment?

Comment: @Łuk don't forget they took into account the option to reply which means five characters are reserved (one for `@`, three first letters of display name and a space) leaving actual minimum of 10 characters.

Comment: @Bohemian I don't think David was around when the code for this was written, although he can now ask Jeff himself. For some unicoins, perhaps? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't really talk to Jeff on a regular basis, and it seems a little silly to send him an email about this :) If there was research, it was probably of the form "What are some crappy comments we don't want to allow?" and set it just longer than that. But probably he just picked a number.

Comment: Thanks @David, your reply is more than what most here expected, I'm pretty sure of that. As for email asking "Hey Jeff, why did you set the minimum comment length to 15?" he'll go after you with some giant letter (maybe T for trivial? ;)) so better not push your luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am asking why it is 15 (and not 14, or 16, etc)?

Perhaps because `15` is the [magic constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_constant) of the unique order-3 [normal magic square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

Seems like a good enough reason!

Moreover it is a:

- [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)
- [hexagonal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_number)
- [pentalope number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatope_number)

Comment: Ah, it's a magical number. I thought so.

Comment: I have no idea what a magical number has to do with minimum comment length limitation...